# Populate an HTML table with XML data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I would like to populate a table with data from an XML file and was thinking along the lines of:

1.) Create the XML data:

```
<menu>
  <pizza>
    <regular>
      <item name="Tomato Cheese">Tomato Cheese
        <price size="small">1</price>
        <price size="large">2</price>
        <description>A</description>
      </item>
      <item name="Onion">Onion
        <price size="small">3</price>
        <price size="large">4</price>
        <description>B</description>
      </item>
    </regular>
  </pizza>
</menu>
```

2.) Create the table in HTML:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Item </th>
      <th rowspan="2">Description</th>
      <th colspan="2">Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Small</th>
      <th>Large</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
```

3.) Use a foreach statement on an XPath query:

```
 foreach  ($xml->xpath('/menu/pizza/descendant::item') as $item)
        {
            print "<tr><td>".$item."</td>" ;
        }
```

This works great for the first row, but I can't figure out how to populate the rest of the columns.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the tags on the question to mention the technologies I think you're actually using here. Please try to include these in future so the right people find your questions.

Comment: You've well described what you've done so far and what your overall goal is. You could turn this into a great programming question if you would add the concrete question you have with this. See as well [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [basic usage examples for SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), you will see that accessing a child element (tag) is done by using `$child = $parent->tagName`, and that for non-unique names, you can use `foreach ( $parent->tagName as $child )`. To access attributes, you use `$tag['attributeName']`.

Here's a few things you could do with `$item` in your code:

- `$name = $item['name'];`
- `$description = $item->description;`
- `foreach ( $item->price as $price ) { ... }`
- inside that loop, `$size = $price['size'];` - this one actually requires you to change your XML a bit, because you have `small="small"`, which will be quite hard to work with; you're better off using `<price size="small">` and `<price size="large">` so everything's consistent

Comment: thanks for clearing up how to access elements, but I think my issue is more about how to automate the whole table to populate;   i.e. mingling the HTML w/ the query and the loop. For ex:  the current loop will create the following code: `<tr><td>$item</td><tr><td>$item</td>` (substituting $item with a different item per the loop). That is, the start of two table rows. What I'm really stuck on is how to get `<td>$description</td></tr>` to be appended to the end of the first row `<tr><td>$item</td>`, then repeat for the second row. I hope I am coming across clearly.

Comment: @user3717955 Just add more `print` statements for whichever HTML tags you need, inside the loop, next to the existing one. PHP doesn't know or care what they mean, it just passes them to the browser. So you could write `print '<'; print 'tr'; print '>';` if you wanted, and the browser would see `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks IMsOP.
Just wanted to follow-up as I have resolved this.

First, I ran the following queries:

```
/* querying the XML data to return arrays containing pizza name, description, small price, large price  
$pName = $xml->xpath("/menu/pizza/regular/descendant::item");
$description = $xml->xpath('/menu/pizza/regular/descendant::item/description');
$sPrice = $xml->xpath('/menu/pizza/regular/descendant::item/price[@size="small"]');
$lPrice = $xml->xpath('/menu/pizza/regular/descendant::item/price[@size="large"]');
```

Then I populated the table using loops.
Here are three different methods in case anybody is interested:

```
/* using a WHILE loop */
$e = 0;
while ( $e < count($pName) )
{
  echo "<tr><th scope='row' class='vHeader'>".$pName[$e]."</th><td>".$description[$e]."</td><td>".$sPrice[$e]."</td><td>".$lPrice[$e]."</td></tr>";
  $e++;
}  

/* using a FOR loop */
for($i = 0 ;$i < count($pName); $i++)
{
  echo "<tr><th scope='row' class='vHeader'>".$pName[$i]."</th><td>".$description[$i]."</td><td>".$sPrice[$i]."</td><td>".$lPrice[$i]."</td></tr>"; 
} 

/* another way using a FOR loop */
for ( $e = 0; $e < count($pName); $e++ ) 
{   
   $name = $pName[$e] ;
   $desc = $description[$e] ;
   $sp = $sPrice[$e] ;
   $lp = $lPrice[$e] ;
   echo "<tr><th scope='row' class='vHeader'>".$name[0]."</th><td>".$desc[0]."</td><td>".$sp[0]."</td><td>".$lp[0]."</td></tr>"; }
```